# How to clear the settings of RapidSVN on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, svn, ubuntu, rapidsvn

For some reason, each time I reach a bookmark on RapidSVN, the app crashes. It doesn't even show me the error. Just closes itself.

I've tried to do a complete removal of the app via Synaptic package manager and then re-install it, but it still has the problematic bookmark.

My question is: how can I clear RapidSVN's app settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings of RapidSVN is apparently stored in the home directory. To purge the config file of the app is as easy as running this command:

```
rm -rf .RapidSVN
```

This command will reset all of the configurations that you have made for RapidSVN. I would suggest you make a backup of the configurations before you purge it though.

Comment: this works , but i still keep getting crashes no matter what SVN working copy i use . is it possible that i need to re-install some SVN components? if so, how? i also wonder how come linux/ubuntu uninstall apps completely , including their configuration files ...

Comment: I think once you open rapidsvn, it segfaults. I suggest you file a bug report and compile a newer version from source.

Comment: i'm not that hardcore . i've used this tool for a very long time but now it just doesn't work . i use PySVN WorkBench instead .

Comment: I am afraid it falls well beyond the scope of this question. You might want to ask a new question and I'll see if I can nail a proper solution for that question.

Comment: well technically you've answered the question , but the question was asked in order to avoid the crash.

Comment: It seems like a bug in the program itself. There are a number of forum posts about this crash and I found at least recent [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=827102) regarding this. I don't think I can help you much here.

Comment: i see . ok then , you got a "V" , even though i am sad at using an alternative . wish i had a turtoise SVN as on windows . i've also tried rabitSVN but it doesn't work at all (or maybe i don't know how to make it useable) .

Comment: Thanks for the check. I would have helped but it is a segfault issue with the application itself. Hopefully, you will be able to sort it out somehow.